# App bar like Google inbox web app

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui, appbar

I am building a react web application. I am using material ui for it. I am looking to have an appbar like google inbox has (screenshot attached below). Currently I have Appbar imported from material ui module, but it just contains title , navigation icon. I want to have a search bar, profile photo etc in my app bar, just like google inbox. How can I customize it to get a design like that. Do I have to tweak with material ui's appbar (if yes then how exactly) or do I have to do something else?

[image: Google Inbox Appbar]

Answer (score 1):

```
const rightButtons = (
<div>
 <FlatButton key={1} label="Btn1"/>
 <FlatButton key={2} label="Btn2" />
<div>
)   //Style as per your requirement, Also implement search textfield component
// Drawer with list items
<Drawer/>
<AppBar
  title="Inbox"
  iconElementLeft={<SearchComponent/>}
  iconElementRight={rightButtons}
  onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleLeftDrawerToggle}
/>
```

make use of iconElementLeft and iconElementRight.
[Docs of AppBar](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar)

Answer (score 0):

As second option, You can use alternate framework [react-materialize](https://react-materialize.github.io/#/navbar) as well, as it has what your requirement is exactly.

```
<Navbar brand='logo' right>
  <NavItem href='get-started.html'><Icon>search</Icon></NavItem>
  <NavItem href='get-started.html'><Icon>view_module</Icon></NavItem>
  <NavItem href='get-started.html'><Icon>refresh</Icon></NavItem>
  <NavItem href='get-started.html'><Icon>more_vert</Icon></NavItem>
</Navbar>
```